# How to add JavaScript dynamically to immediately above </body> tag?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of JavaScript code that is to be added at the end of `<body>` tag, that is  immediately above `</body>`. The JavaScript can not be added directly to the page. It is inserted to the browser end by an external tool. This js code is to be placed immediately above `</body>` tag as shown below.

```
<head>
something
</head>

<body>
some html/js
some html/js
........
my js code here
</body>
```

How can I do this ? Is there any way to accomplish this without coding in page but only as part of js code in external tool ? I am allowed to write only JavaScript in tool.

My basic question is how to insert script just before `</body>` tag when the script is to be written somewhere else ?

Comment: How could we know what this unspecified external tool can do? Anything might be possible. Or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use do it like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(SCRIPT_NODE_HERE);
```

Also if you are using Ajax then you should put your code in the event that says the script loaded successfully and ready to be executed

One thing here though, if you want to load the script dynamically then there is no point of loading it just before the `</body>` tag because it gives you no benefit.

Developers usually put the script near the end of the body so that it reduces page load times, and delays script execution to some extent until the page has finished loading so it doesn't block other content and cause unpleasant experience to the client.

So when you load your script dynamically, your page would have already downloaded its resources and there will be no blocking.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It shuld have been posted as a comment.

Comment: +1 just a small correction: "asynchronous loading" not "dynamically loading"

Comment: BTW, even though this doesn't answer the OP question - it is certainly useful, hence the +1.

Comment: @alfasin I agree, I didn't say so, and I didn't try to imply that it is.

Comment: The script makes use of some js objects/DOM elements. So it is necessary that all of the js objects / DOM elements should be available before this script is executed. Hence it is to be added immediately before </body> tag.

Comment: @RaheebM read again: when you load JS asynchronously - you can't control which objects were loaded and hence "injecting" it just before the body tag closes - is not useful. Another option is that you used the word "asynchronous" by mistake.

Comment: Actually the loading is asynchronous, but that problem has overcome in other way. Anyway let me correct my question.

Comment: @RaheebM I have modified my answer a bit to show you how to insert an element at the end of the page.

Comment: var script = document.createElement("script"); document.body.appendChild(script );
Is this the way you are telling ? The script will be appended just before </body> by this way ?

Comment: @RaheebM Yes. That should get the job done, of course if you are loading the script dynamically after the page has already loaded, if you put this in a script in the head tag outside of the page loaded event then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Loading the script in a page dynamically equals page has already loaded. I didn't get this point.

Comment: @RaheebM First off, where are you putting the code to load the dynamic script, and how are you loading it ?

Comment: One partner provided order tracking js code for the ecommerce site I am working on, and they instructed to put this code immediately before </body>. But we are not placing this code directly in jsp.It will be done by an external tool(we are placing the code in the tool). The tool will inject this code at the browser level. Now, we need to make sure that the tool places the code just before </body>. In tool we should do this using js/DOM methods. This is my concern.
Please correct me if there is any mistake in my understanding in js concept.

Comment: @RaheebM I mean the code you posted, `var script = document.createScript(); document.body.appendChild(script);` should work correctly.

Comment: So if we use this method document.body.appendChild(script), this script will be executed only after all the body elements are loaded ? Is that the concept ?

Comment: @RaheebM I am starting to get confused here, so I don't know what to tell you. Try it out it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    your js code here
  }
 }
```

load this into the page using your tool, I believe *wherever* it is loaded in the page, it will execute once the page's readystate changes and when the page is completely loaded your code will execute.

Comment: It may be a problem if I use event handlers since I have to do the same thing for different code snippet

Comment: like I said, your code will execute after the page is completely loaded and ready with all the DOM elements, Hence your event handlers should work.

Comment: I understood. But can I use like this ?
document.onreadystatechange = function (){script1}
document.onreadystatechange = function (){script2}
document.onreadystatechange = function (){script3}

Comment: in that case add your seperate script codes in seperate functions and call all those functions in the `document.onreadystatechange` lastly.

Comment: The problem is each js code is provided by different vendors. We need to create separate code snippet for each vendor code and fun within one snippet can't be called by other snippet. Can I accomplish this by a combination of js & DOM methods ?